# How to use Java jar library with only one file in it? What is this file?

Tags: java, jar

I have to use this java library https://efs.uspto.gov/TruePassSampleApp/servlets/AppletDownloadServlet/entrusttruepassapplet.jar but this JAR contains single file and i don't know what that file is. Can anyone hint me how to use such JAR?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be meant to run as a library.

Comment: How do you *want* to use it?

Comment: I just want to include it in my project. I have seen it loaded like this: this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("EntrustTruePassApplet"); but first I need to somehow "link" this jar with my project.

Comment: What kind of project do you have? What build tool and IDE are you using? If you have added any other jar, you can add it the same way.

Comment: I just never encountered a JAR with only one file in it with no extension. i just need to know what it is.